# Load JQuery first, then show html page contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a mobile site, unfortunately I can't direct access to do anything on HTML, so I'm using JQuery to style its width, height etc., the problem is the site has actually 762px width(which is a normal site for PC) and I gave 320px width(for an iPhone screen), everything works well but at the time when page loads it comes from the middle of the page to fit the 320px screen size. I strongly believe that my JQuery code for width(320px, although I specified Jquery for some other elements too) is taking action after the contents loaded in the html page.

(I saw this problem on Opera mobile emulator 320x480)

So if I can able to load the JQuery first then the contents(HTML) in the page may solve the issue. You guys have any suggestions?

my script is given below..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />');
$("table.bgContent").removeAttr("width");
$("table.bgContent").attr("width","320");
$("table.cart-header").removeAttr("width");
$("table.cart-header").css("background","none");
$("table.cart-header").css("border","none");
$("table.cart-header td:first").html('<a href="home.aspx"><img src="images/userdir/logomobile.gif" width="320" height="79" border="0"/></a>');
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />');
$("table:eq(2) td.bgHeaderBarCart").html(" ");
$('table.cart-header td:nth-child(2)').css('display', 'none');
$('hr').css('width','300px');
$('td.FormTextCart').removeAttr("width");
$('.cart-header').css('height','0px');
$('.ContentAreaCart').css('padding','0px');
$('.SpanOrderCenter').css({padding : '0px',   textAlign : 'left', fontWeight : 'normal', fontSize : '12px', width : '300px'});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a wrapper `<div>` within your `<body>` tag, for example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="display:none;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

then on document ready in your js file, add:

```
$("#wrapper").show();
```

Comment: Thanks Luc for the suggestion, but unfortunately I don't have permission to access the html to add a div just like you said..